# python script to find the max to combine

Tags: python

I have two files in this format

1.txt

what i want to do is  to merge both these files by considering the first column and append the output as following 
expected output

my script i have written is not working

```
file1=raw_input('Enter the first file name: ')
file2=raw_input('Enter the second file name: ')

with open(file1, 'r') as  f1:
  with open(file2, 'r') as  f2:
    mydict = {}
    for row in f1:
      mydict[row[0]] = row[1:]
    for row in f2:
      mydict[row[0]] = mydict[row[0]].extend(row[1:])

fout = csv.write(open('out.txt','w'))
for k,v in mydict:
  fout.write([k]+v)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should work:

```
import csv

d_1 = {}

with open('1.csv') as f_1:
    for row in csv.reader(f_1):
        d_1[row[0]] = row[4:]

with open('2.csv') as f_2, open('out.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)

    for row in csv.reader(f_2):
        if row[0] in d_1:
            row.extend(d_1[row[0]])

        csv_out.writerow(row)
```

This first reads `1.csv` into a dictionary, leaving out the first three columns. It then reads each entry in `2.csv`, and if the first column matches an entry in the dictionary, it appends the result before writing to the output.

Note: Entries present in `1.csv` but not in `2.csv` will be ignored. Secondly, entries in `2.csv` which are not in `1.csv` are written unchanged.

This gives you an `out.csv` file as follows:

```
223456,233,334,334,45,667,445,6667,77798,881,2234,44556,3333,22334,44555,22233,22334,22222,22334,2234,2233,222,55,666666
333883,445,445,4445,44,556,555,333,44445,5556,5555,223,334,5566,334,445,667,334,556,776,45,2223,3334,4444
```

---

For Python 2.6, split the `with` onto two lines as follows:

```
import csv

d_1 = {}

with open('1.csv') as f_1:
    for row in csv.reader(f_1):
        d_1[row[0]] = row[4:]

with open('2.csv') as f_2:
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f_out:
        csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)

        for row in csv.reader(f_2):
            if row[0] in d_1:
                row.extend(d_1[row[0]])

            csv_out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: `csv_out.writerow(row)` should be inside if clause.

Comment: That would delete any existing entries in `2.csv` that did not have an enty in `1.csv`

Comment: i think you are also writing rows not satisfying the if clause

Comment: Thanks for your script, but i dont want the first 3 columns from 1.csv, as the expected output

Comment: Not a problem, I have updated the script for you. Just store columns four onwards into the dictionary.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Older versions probably need two `with` statements.

Comment: I'm guessing you might be on Python 2.6, the second number is important. I have added a second version that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your script doesn't work because you have made a few inaccuraces.

1. `row` is a string, so `row[0]` is the first character, not the first number.
2. The method `.extend` returns nothing, so it doesn't make a sense to use `=`.

I would fix your script in this way:

```
import csv

mydict = {}
with open('1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        mydict[row[0]] = row[1:]

with open('2.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as fout:
        writer = csv.writer(fout)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = row + mydict[row[0]]
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
file1=raw_input('Enter the first file name: ')
file2=raw_input('Enter the second file name: ')

with open(file1, 'r') as  f1:
    r1 = f1.read()

with open(file2, 'r') as  f2:
    r2 = f2.read()

with open('out.txt','w') as o2:
    o2.write('{0},{1}'.format(r1, r2))
```